# Basecamp json api post todo

Tags: json, post, google-code, basecamp

Tried to learn the `json` api for `Basecamp`.

Get requests are working fine for me, but I cant seem to get the post requests to work.
Using Google Script. 
Can anyone see the bug? I keep getting a 403, even though I am owner of the account and the project

```
function createBaseCampTodo(user, pw, email, appName, accountNumber,
                            projectNumber,todolistNumber) {  

  var url = "https://basecamp.com/"+accountNumber+"/api/v1/projects/"
             +projectNumber+"/todolists/"+todolistNumber+"/todos.json"; 

  var headers = {
                 "User-Agent": appName + " ("+email+")",
                 "contentType": "application/json",
                 "Authorization": "Basic " + 
                                   Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + pw)
                 };

  var data = {
  "content": "This is my new thing!",
  "due_at": "2015-03-27"
  };              

  var params = {
    "method":"post",
    "headers":headers,
    "validateHttpsCertificates" :false,
    //"muteHttpExceptions" : true,
    "payload" : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var text = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy of mine found the bug. It should say Content-Type instead of contentType.
Points to him for his sharp mind and eyes.